# YII 1.1 Failed to Execute the SQL Statement, Invalid Parameter

Tags: php, yii

I have inherited a YII framework project, and am in the process of migrating to a better server. I have fixed most of the errors but now I am getting the following error.

```
Internal Server error

CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number
```

I have narrowed it down to the following bits of code.

```
// First Query    

        $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $criteria->addCondition('entertainer_id = :entertainerid');
        $criteria->addCondition('datetime_start <= :sdate' );
        $criteria->addCondition('datetime_end > :sdate' );
        $criteria->params = array(':entertainerid'=>$entertainer_id, ':sdate' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $inc_start));
        $scheduled =  EntertainerSchedule::model()->count($criteria);

// Second Query

        $inc_end = $inc_start + $inc_seconds;
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $criteria->addCondition('entertainer_id = :entertainerid');
        $criteria->addCondition('datetime_start <= :sdate' );
        $criteria->addCondition('datetime_end > :sdate' );
        $criteria->addCondition('status != :statusCancel' );
        $criteria->params = array(':entertainerid'=>$entertainer_id, ':sdate' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $inc_start), ':statusCancel'=>Reservation::STATUS_CANCELLED);
        $reserved =  Reservation::model()->count($criteria);
```

The site is currently working on it's old server, I've tried downgrading php versions on the new server and that did not fix the errors, it made it worse.

This is my first YII framework project I have ever worked on, and I didn't write the code. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your first query, there are **3** variables but you are only passing **2**. Similarly, in your second query there are **4** variables but you are only passing **3**.

Your assumption is that since two variables are same, i.e. `:sdate`, passing it once should be sufficient but that's not so. You need to pass it as many times as they are being used in the query.

So, these queries should look as below.

```
    // First Query    
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->addCondition('entertainer_id = :entertainerid');
    $criteria->addCondition('datetime_start <= :sdate' );
    $criteria->addCondition('datetime_end > :sdate' );
    $criteria->params = array(':entertainerid'=>$entertainer_id, ':sdate' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $inc_start), ':sdate' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $inc_start));
    $scheduled =  EntertainerSchedule::model()->count($criteria);

    // Second Query
    $inc_end = $inc_start + $inc_seconds;
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->addCondition('entertainer_id = :entertainerid');
    $criteria->addCondition('datetime_start <= :sdate' );
    $criteria->addCondition('datetime_end > :sdate' );
    $criteria->addCondition('status != :statusCancel' );
    $criteria->params = array(':entertainerid'=>$entertainer_id, ':sdate' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $inc_start), ':sdate' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $inc_start), ':statusCancel'=>Reservation::STATUS_CANCELLED);
    $reserved =  Reservation::model()->count($criteria);
```